# how to get the duration of an mp4 file(h.264 standard)

Tags: video, h.264, mp4, mpeg

I want to get some information of an mp4 file , I try to use Shell32 , but it does not support mp4 format , I have found some dlls in the website , but all they are not COM component , then I try to use IBMToolkitForMpeg4SDK.jar , and then meets some problems:

```
***Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: Unrecognized extension of file: e:\1.mpeg
at I4g.d(Unknown Source)
at I4g.a(Unknown Source)
at I4i.a(Unknown Source)
at I4b.a(Unknown Source)
at I4b.open(Unknown Source)
at AVgenSample.getMp4Duration(AVgenSample.java:48)
at AVgenSample.main(AVgenSample.java:36)***
```

So I want to get the information of mp4 file , anyone have any methods , please help!Thsnks all!

Comment: answer http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/387013/how-to-get-the-information-of-an-mp4-file-h-264-st

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting MP4 File Duration with DirectShow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346136/getting-mp4-file-duration-with-directshow)

Answer (score 0):

if you mean ISO file - [this java library](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) might help.

Use it to navigate to `moov->trak->mdia->mdhd`

or Elecard Video Format Analyzer http://www.elecard.com/en/download/products.html#development